# how to trigger a process when a signal is affected even with the same value as the old?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I want a process to be triggered whenever a signal is affected even with the same value as the old one.
If I use `wait on 'signal';` if the signal is affected with '1' when it will be again affected with '1' it will not trigger the process because it has not changed the value to '0'. I want the process to be triggered each time the signal gets a value even if it is the same.
does anyone have any Idea how to do it ?
thank you for the help

Comment: There's also`wait until some_signal'active;` where this predefined attribute is a function.

Comment: See for example IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.2.4 Predefined attributes of signals. While a little research effort would deny Tricky some reputation for easy answers it'd enhance your independence from the results of easy questions. You could also provide a [mcve] so future readers could understand the problem and answer better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `'transaction` attribute. `'transaction` is a signal of type `bit` that toggles whenever a signal assignment occurs. hence you can use

```vhdl
wait on some_sig'transaction;
```

to halt a process and wait for a signal assignment.

This will only be suitable for simulation, as this make no sense in any current form of hardware.

Comment: Note the particular lack of explanation involving the definition of event and transaction in the VHDL standard. *does anyone have any Idea how to do it ?* is too broad.